# Schrodinger on lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, lattice-model

If I were to represent the state of a system (i.e. a function $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb C$) on a lattice (i.e. a function $\mathbb Z\mathbf i+\mathbb Z\mathbf j + \mathbb Z \mathbf k\to \mathbb C$) can I still count on the Hamiltonian being hermitian (i.e. $\langle \phi|H|\phi\rangle\in\mathbb R$, $ \forall \phi$) or is it possible to get complex expectation values, if so how should I penalize, it having imaginary part?

Answer (score 1):

There are several separate issues: physically, you have to distinguish between discrete/lattice models where the wave function $\psi : \mathbb{Z}^d \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and models on the continuum. Lattice models are often used to approximate continuum models (e. g. in solid state physics). Hamiltonians for discrete quantum systems of course define hermitian operators on the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ of square summable sequences, and thus, their spectrum is purely real. If you arrive at the discrete Hamiltonian through an approximation procedure from a hermitian continuum Hamiltonian, then the procedure has to ensure that the approximate discrete Hamiltonian is again hermitian.

The second issue is mathematical: the Hilbert spaces $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$ composed of square integrable functions and square summable sequences, respectively, are separable Hilbert spaces, which means they have a countable dense set. Equivalently, they have a countable basis. Thus, there exists a unitary map $U : L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) \longrightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^d)$, i. e. you can represent any continuum model on the lattice. In one dimension this is quite easy to see:  simply pick a countable basis (you could use the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator), and you number them appropriately (e. g. $n \mapsto (n-1)/2$ if $n$ is even and $n \mapsto (2n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd).

Answer (score 0):

That is entirely up to what you choose as Hamiltonian. In $L_2(\mathbb R^3)$, you can choose hermitian Hamiltonians (like $\nabla^2$) and non-hermitian ones (like $\frac{d}{dx}$). Similarly, in $L_2(\mathbb Z^3)$, you can choose hermitian Hamiltonians (like $$\phi_{i,j,k}\mapsto \phi_{i+1,j,k} + \phi_{i,j+1,k} + \phi_{i,j,k+1} + \phi_{i-1,j,k} + \phi_{i,j-1,k} + \phi_{i,j,k-1} - 6\phi_{ijk},$$ the naive discrete Laplacian) and non-hermitian ones (like $\phi_{i,j,k}\mapsto \phi_{i+1,j,k}-\phi_{i-1,j,k}$, the naive discrete $x$ derivative). Both are possible, and the criteria for telling whether a given operator is or isn't hermitian are exactly the same.